# Including dynamic auto suggest javascript code in twig

Tags: symfony-3.4

I wanted to add an auto suggest list of students' code into input box

```
public function autoCodeSuggest()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT s.studentLogin FROM AppBundle:StudentLogin s ORDER BY s.studentLogin");
    $code = $query->getArrayResult();
    $strJavascript = '';
    if (!empty($code)){
      $strJavascript = '
      var ArrayCode = new Array(';
      for ($i=0; $i<count($code); $i++){
          $strJavascript .=  '"'.$code[$i]['studentLogin'].'",';
      } // for ($i=0; $i<count($code); $i++)
      $n = strlen($strJavascript)-1;
      $strJavascript = substr_replace($strJavascript,'',$n); // remove last ,
      $strJavascript .= ');';
    } // if (!empty($code))
    return $strJavascript;
} // end function
```

in my controller

```
public function studentSearchAction()
{
    $LoginJS = $this->get('utilities_student_tools')->autoCodeSuggest();
    return $this->render('student/student_search.html.twig', array(
        'LoginJS' => $LoginJS,
    ));
}
```

student_search.html.twig contains

```
{% block body %}
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
{{ LoginJS }}
</script>
{{ include('student_code.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

it doesn't work because when I view the source code of my page I have

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var ArrayCode = new Array(&quot;AA0951&quot;,&quot;AA1825&quot;,&quot;AA2802&quot;,&quot;AA2886&quot;,&quot;AA3418&quot;,.....
</script>
```

when I add a \ to the javascript code generator

```
$strJavascript .=  '\"'.$code[$i]['studentLogin'].'\",';
```

the output become

```
var ArrayCode = new Array(\&quot;AA0951\&quot;,\&quot;AA1825\&quot;,\&quot;AA2802\&quot;,\&quot;AA2886\&quot;
```

It works if the output is like

```
var ArrayCode = new Array("AA0951","AA1825","AA2802","AA2886",

the " is converted to &quot; .
```

How can I avoid the conversion in twig?

Answer (score 0):

I just find the answer.

```
{{ LoginJS|raw }}
```